# Python websockets client library - not detecting close from server?

Tags: python, websocket

I have a server (Bootstrap Java) which serves websockets.
I'm trying to use the python websockets library to build an integration test framework, but I am not familiar with python asyncio so I think I am making some beginner mistakes!

I have created my websocket with

```
    async def __async_connect(self, address):
    print("opening websocket on ", address)
    self.ws = await websockets.connect(address)

    def open_connection(self, address, firmware_version="103"):
    if self.ws is None:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.__async_connect(address))
```

and can send/receive messages.
However, when the server decides to close the websocket, the python client continues to run, and will even send messages to it with

message = await self.ws.send(json.dumps(message))

I tested using the websocket client chrome extension, which correctly determines that the server has closed the connection.  I also tested with ping_interval=None to see if it was the pings keeping the connection alive, but it is not.
Am I missing something that would allow the python to detect that the server has closed the connection?  Am I not closing the websockets correctly, despite the fact that both the chrome extension and websocket-client were able to detect the close?

Comment: Try to find some example with using on_connect and on_close function. It might help.

Comment: Here it is : https://pypi.org/project/websocket_client/

Comment: Hi @Raxodius - thanks for the fast response, but that's actually a different library.  I'm using the python "websockets" library, which is based on asyncio.  Unfortunately there were a number of issues with the library that you linked, including that it didn't support python 3.8+.

Comment: So maybe try to write function like: server sends some message when closing, client looking for this message and when it appears than it close itself. The simplest solution that comes to my mind.

Comment: Did you try this : https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment.html#graceful-shutdown

Comment: Hi @raxodius - aren't those pages for the websocket server?  I am not using that, only the client.  I can't see a way to apply the documentation you linked to the client, do you have a working example?